# How to impl git-hook to change message of a merge with `no fast forward`?

Tags: git, githooks

I make:

`Android Studio`-> `VCS`-> `Git`-> `Merge Changes...`

Check `No fast forward`

[image]

After that 
[image]

So I want to change commit message `"Merge branch 'GRAM-1087' into develop"` to `GRAM-1087 is merged to develop and is #done`

Currently I have githook: `prepare-commit-msg` for adding name of branch to commit message:

```
#!/bin/sh

target_branch="develop"

last_develop=`git log origin/$target_branch| head -n 1|cut -f 2 -d ' '`;

parent=`git log | head -n 1|cut -f 2 -d ' '`;

current_branch=`git branch|grep '* '|cut -f 1 -d '_'|cut -f 2 -d ' '`;

if [ $target_branch != $current_branch ]; then
if [ "$last_develop" == "$parent" ]; then
echo "$current_branch : #in-progress #comment $(cat $1)" > "$1"
else
echo "$current_branch : #comment $(cat $1)" > "$1"
fi
fi
```

Comment: post-merge won't help you, because the content of the commit, including the message, is etched in stone by that time.

Comment: @JanHudec I found that `prepare-commit-msg` catch the message and can be modified in it. But how to get target and source branch?

Comment: The prepare-commit-msg hook gets a file containing the initial message, which you'll have to read. Note that it's also used for *non-merge* commits, so you should check whether the commit is a merge before trying to replace the message. See the [githooks documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks/) for details.